# Understanding Theorem 19.2 in Munkres

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> **Theorem 19.2 in Munkres** Suppose the topology on each space $X_{\alpha}$ is given by a basis $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha}$. The collection of all sets of the form $$\prod_{\alpha \in J} B_{\alpha}$$ where $B_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{B}_{\alpha}$ for each ${\alpha}$, will serve as a basis for the box topology on $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$

The problem I'm having with understanding the theorem is due to the use of the indices.

---

From what I understand the above theorem is saying that *the collection of all possible sets formed* by:

Taking **one** arbitrary basis element from each arbitrary basis $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha}$, and then taking the product of each of those basis elements

forms a basis for the box topology $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$.

---

Is my understanding correct? 
I apologize in advance if this question is somewhat vague.

Comment: Yes, I think what you have written is fine. An element of the basis of the large product, is a product of one basic set from each component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.  The open sets in the box topology on $\displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ will be unions of basis elements.  The basis elements are of the form $\displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in J} B_\alpha$, where each $B_\alpha$ is some basis element for $X_\alpha$.

Perhaps more simply, the basis for the box topology can be defined in terms of open sets.  That is, $\displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ has as a basis $\displaystyle \left\{ \prod_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha \ \Big| \ U_\alpha \text{ is open in } X_\alpha \right\}$.

---

As a side note, we typically choose the product topology over the box topology in practice; I'm sure this'll come up shortly in Munkres.  The product topology is defined as we defined the box topology in the second paragraph above, but with the added stipulation that $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha \in J$.  Though this seemingly more complicated, the product topology satisfies more "desirable" things.  Some examples off the top of my head include:

- The product of compact spaces will be compact.
- A function $f: Y \rightarrow \displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is continuous $\iff$ each $(\pi_\alpha \circ f): Y \rightarrow X_\alpha$ is continuous, where $\pi_\alpha$ denotes the projection map from the product space onto $X_\alpha$.

Lastly, note that the product topology and the box topology are the same thing unless we are looking at the product of infinitely many $X_\alpha$.

Comment: I think you mean $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$ in the second sentence after the break.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right @Stahl.  The distinction between box and product topologies is similar to the difference between direct product and direct sum of algebraic structures, and I got some ideas mixed up in my hurry to post.  Thanks!